# manage.py runserver not working

Tags: mysql, django, settings

I am new to django and python in general, so pardon me for any simple mistakes I may be doing.  I am trying to setup my first django project on my local windows vista machine.  I have created the project successfully with no problems.  The issue I am coming across is when my settings.py has values for my database keys, the manage.py runserver command is failing.  If I have values in settings before I run the command, as soon as I run it I get errors.  If I have already run the command and the server is running, as soon as I edit the settings file with values, the errors show up in my still open command prompt.  The inner most exception seems to "**Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MYSQLdb**".  If I leave the settings.py blank, the command executes with no problems.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have mysql-python module installed, thats why you getting that error.

You could find that module at

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/

Answer (score 2):

Install the `MySQLdb` module, or the `oursql` module along with the `django-oursql` connector.